# Risk of Adding Third-Party Google Tag Manager To WebSite

Tags: javascript, security, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, facebook-pixel

I am creating a marketplace application and I want to let my sellers to add their Google Tag Manager to product pages and checkout success page. I am not very familiar with marketing tools, but as far as I know, it is possible to add custom scripts through the GTM.

My question is, how far can this scripts go and if this may cause any security issue to my application? 
I also know there is also the whitelist and blacklist. My goal is to allow only google scripts and facebook pixel information to run through the GTM, so I came with this datalayer:

```
var dataLayer = [{
  "gtm.whitelist": ["google","customPixels"]
  "gtm.blacklist": ["customScripts"]
}];
```

The GTM script will be loaded only inside specific seller products and when the checkout success page has any of the seller product. No other pages will load the script. Is this of high risk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **My question is, how far can this scripts go and if this may cause any
>   security issue to my application?**

As far as JavaScript can go (since a GTM container is nothing else than some JS code being executed in the browser). **It could be a massive security risk**, for instance someone could add a tag with a [`keydown` listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and capture every single user keystrokes, including passwords etc...

> **My goal is to allow only google scripts and facebook pixel information
>   to run through the GTM, so I came with this datalayer:**

Yes this would already be better.

> **The GTM script will be loaded only inside specific seller products and
>   when the checkout success page has any of the seller product. No other
>   pages will load the script. Is this of high risk?**

Doing the **below should prevent external GTM containers from causing security risk**:

1. Set a GTM whitelist only on safe tags (GA, FB pixel...)
2. Only allow sellers to provide their GTM container ID (`GTM-XXXXXXXX`)
3. Generate and insert the GTM container loading snippet based on 2.

**Don't allow your users to copy/paste their GTM container snippet**,as one could overwrite and circumvent your dataLayer whitelist inside that snippet (window.dataLayer=[]).

Comment: I found the Tags on this URL https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/restrict but no reference to Facebook Pixel can be found. Do you have any information if Facebook pixel belongs to customScripts or customPixels Tag?

Comment: The FB pixel tag, like other tags of Google direct  Ad competitors (eg Bing Ads) are not present in Google Tag Manager, people have to add them via a custom script (I believe this is a small effort from Google to simply facilitate the rollout of Google Ads vs. Facebook Ads and Bing Ads). Not sure if possible, but in https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/restrict have a look at the `sandboxedScripts` type for the use of custom templates (eg FB custom template: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/create-facebook-pixel-custom-tag-template/), maybe you can whitelist certain templates...